# Gradle asking for different build tools version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

[image]

I'm trying to start a new project in Android Studio and I'm getting the following error: *Gradle is trying to use Build Tools version 23.0.1 but I explicitly told it to use 23.0.3.*

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to install `Build Tools 23.0.1`?

Comment: Well the Build Tools themselves may or may not be self-contained, so having every incremental update may be necessary. In my `SDK Manager` I do have `0.1`, `0.2` & `0.3` so I would try that.

Comment: Well, I downloaded 23.0.1 and it just started working, I kept the buildtoolsversion to 23.0.3 on my gradle file, I doubt that's the version it's using though.. well, gradle will continue to be a mystery to me, moving on Thanks for the help @DanielK !

Comment: No problem glad I could help. I'll leave more specific instructions for others in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the easy solution of clicking `Install Build Tools 23.0.1 and sync project`, you can also install any build tool in the following screen. Go to:

[image]

Then `SDK Tools`, then check `Show Package Details`, pick any you want & then hit `Apply`:

[image]

Then it'll take you through an installation screen & you're done.